# VIM: Stay away from the edges on searches

Tags: search, vim

I recently saw some VIM configuration where search matches would scroll to N lines past the match, so that there would be N lines below the search match instead of it being on the last line (to give context). I cannot find the page where this was mentioned, and apparently I do not know the right keywords to google for!

What is this feature called, and how could I have used the VIM manual to find it assuming that I don't know what it is called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I tell this can't be set just for search, but is a setting that will be used in all situations.

You are looking for `scrolloff`: Minimal number of screen lines to keep above and below the cursor. This will make some context visible around where you are working. `sidescrolloff` does the same thing but horizontally.

This is what I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
" When the page starts to scroll, keep the cursor 8 lines from the top and 8
" lines from the bottom and 15 lines on the left
set scrolloff=8
set sidescrolloff=15
set sidescroll=1
```